# Elegant way to change either to error with tagless final

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, cats-effect, tagless-final

I often do things like:

```
import cats.effect.Sync
import cats.implicits._

case class User(name: String)
case object Error extends Exception

def validate[F[_]: Sync](name: String): F[Either[Error, User]] = Sync[F].pure(User(name).asRight)

def doSomething[F[_]: Sync]: F[User] = for {
   maybeUser <- validate("Name")
   user <- maybeUser.fold(Sync[F].raiseError[User](_), Sync[F].pure(_))
} yield user
```

In nutshell, it means if `Either` is `left` then use `raiseError`, if it's `right` just return value.

Is there a more convenient way to *"unwrap"* `Either`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `liftTo` from the cats `Either` syntax: `maybeUser.liftTo[F]`.

You can also use `rethrow`, from the cats `MonadError` syntax, directly on `F[Either[Error, User]]`:

```scala
def doSomething[F[_]: Sync]: F[User] = validate[F]("Name").rethrow
```

Note that you don't actually need `Sync` - `MonadError[*[_], Throwable]` is sufficient.